# JavaScript Isotope- How to manage dynamic data set (re-initialize Isotope)

Tags: javascript, css, dynamic, jquery-isotope

I want to design a website which shows the simple search results with `Isotope` appearance.
I have a text input and get the query from the user and retrieve the search results from my server. So, by changing the query, my data and filtering options change. I don't know how to manage this dynamic data with `Isotope`.

After each query and data change, when I set the new isotope properties and filters in `$container.isotope`, the data blocks become invisible and `Isotope` functions, like animation and filtering, didn't work anymore.

Does anybody know how to manage dynamic data set with Isotope? And how to re-set (re-initialize) Isotope settings after changing of the data set (data blocks)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself! We can use insert and remove function of Isotope.
http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/adding-items.html