# Initializing isotope with dynamic data json

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

I have searched around but no help. My issue is I am using the isotope jQuery library to show data (of course) and I am trying to do this by using a dynamic json dataset. I placed the data in a .json file and I'm reading it in and parsing information, then placing that info in divs under my container div like so:

```
$('#infoContainer').append('<div class="hospital ' + $number + '"><p>' + i + '<br />' + hospital.address + '<br />' + hospital.citystatezip + '</p></div>');
```

Of course that portion is in an .each() function for each hospital. My problem is that the initialization code won't show the dynamic divs like it shows when you manually type them. I'm using what is given on the isotope website:

```
$('#infoContainer').isotope({
                  itemSelector: '.hospital'
              });
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you initialize isotope properly from the browser's console after the data has loaded in? Or, could you post more of your code so we can see what's going on?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I honestly just figured it out after I asked. The answer is in another question. You have to use the insert method but when I tried the first time, I didn't format my string correctly. Here's the link to the other http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14847381/javascript-isotope-how-to-manage-dynamic-data-set-re-initialize-isotope

Comment: Good to hear it :D You might want to answer your own question or close it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is found on this question: [JavaScript Isotope- How to manage dynamic data set (re-initialize Isotope)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14847381/javascript-isotope-how-to-manage-dynamic-data-set-re-initialize-isotope)

I needed to use the insert method.